# How can I derive "whole factor" significance in a brms model with multiple factors?

Tags: r, modeling, bayesian, factors, brms

I am running a simple model in brms with default priors using two multi-level factors (community type, and a quantile grouping).

```
rate_temp_comm <-brms::brm(rate ~ Community  + quantilegroup + (1|Site),
data = rates, family = gaussian, chains = 3,
iter = 4000, warmup = 1000)
```

My summary makes sense, and the differences between the groupings align with my understanding of the dataset:

```
Effects:
           Estimate       Est.Error l-95% CI u-95%    CI      Rhat     Bulk_ESS 
Intercept       0.01402   0.00467  0.00425  0.02336 1.00116     1707     1180
CommunityMix   -0.00852   0.00218 -0.01289 -0.00422 1.00015     7491     4866
CommunityShrub -0.00720   0.00233 -0.01206 -0.00276 1.00019     7188     5095

quantilegroup2 -0.00027   0.00256 -0.00534  0.00474 1.00016     8475     6437
quantilegroup3  0.00178   0.00249 -0.00317  0.00666 1.00117     8613     6694
quantilegroup4 -0.00122   0.00240 -0.00611  0.00347 1.00049     7409     6101
```

So my questions are:

1. When reporting the output of this model, I would ideally like to be able to report both the estimate and the CI for the whole factor. I can see here breakdowns of the levels within these factors and that's helpful but doesn't ease interpretation (when I want to be able to state whether Community type drives or does not drive differences in rate). Whether or not the levels overlap zero or not is interesting but I'd like to go further. Is there a brms version of an F statistic? Or is this a case for leave-one-out analysis?
2. The intercept uses CommunityGrass and quantilegroup1 as the 'baseline' condition, if I'm reading this right. And instead of looking at the CI of the intercept, I should be more interested in the relative differences in intercept and quantilegroup2 and CommunityMix, respectively, correct? Just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly!
   Any advice on interpretation (or additional analyses to parse this out) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!